# Animating objects via ID in kivy

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to animate a graphic in kivy. Since all my inputs will be coming from the keyboard, I need to have object references in python, however I still want to set up the widgets in the kv file. To do this I found the only way to trigger anything from python was using IDs. However when trying to start an animation via ID the object doesn't move. Printing the x coordinate shows a change, although I don't see it move.

Here is my main.py:

```
import threading
import time
import keyboard
from kivy.app import App, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager, NoTransition
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.animation import Animation, AnimationTransition


class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass


class OtherScreen(Screen):
    pass


def left_animate(object):
    anim = Animation(x=object.x - 40, transition='in_back')
    anim.start(object)


class RootWidget(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RootWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.screenman = ScreenManager()
        self.screenman.add_widget(MainScreen(name="main"))
        self.screenman.add_widget(OtherScreen(name="other"))
        self.add_widget(self.screenman)

        x = threading.Thread(target=self.keyboard_thread)
        x.start()

    def keyboard_thread(self):
        print("Thread started")
        while True:
            if keyboard.is_pressed('h'):
                self.key_event('h')
            elif keyboard.is_pressed('j'):
                self.key_event('j')
            elif keyboard.is_pressed('left'):
                self.left_pressed()

    def left_pressed(self):
        if self.screenman.current == 'main':
            anim = Animation(x = 40)
            print(self.ids.main.ids.img_ok.x)
            anim.start(self.ids.main.ids.img_ok)

    def key_event(self, key):
        if key == 'h':
            self.screenman.current = "main"
        else:
            self.screenman.current = "other"


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

and this is the .kv file:

```
<RootWidget>:
    ScreenManager:
        MainScreen:
            id: main
        OtherScreen:
            id: other

<MainScreen>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: root.pos
            size: root.size
    Image:
        id: img_ok
        source: '../graphics/icons8-abstimmung-80.png'
        pos: 200, 200
<OtherScreen>:
    Button:
        text: 'Go to main screen'
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'main'
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you are building two `ScreenManagers`. One is built in the `__init__()` method of `RootWidget`. The other is being built by `kv` when it evaluates the `<RootWidget>:` rule in your `.kv` file. Both of those `ScreenManagers` fill the `RootWidget` and one obscures the other. I believe that your `Animation` is moving the `Image` widget, but it is underneath and not visible.

I suggest that you start fixing this by eliminating:

```
    self.screenman = ScreenManager()
    self.screenman.add_widget(MainScreen(name="main"))
    self.screenman.add_widget(OtherScreen(name="other"))
    self.add_widget(self.screenman)
```

from the `__init__()` method. That will force additional changes to your code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added the screenmanager to the kv file, so that I could access its widgets via IDs, without this I found no way to access the image from python. Removing the screenmanager in the python part leaves me then with no reference to it in python. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: The `ScreenManager` was already in your `kv` file, so you don't need to add it again. And you can assign an `id` to the `ScreenManager` so you can access it by using its `id`.